# Ignorar acentuação ao usar busca no menu (input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Eu criei um `input` search e uma lista (menu lateral) abaixo, quando faço a pesquisa está ok, mas estou com problema quando alguma `<li>` tem palavra com acentuação.

Como eu poderia implementar uma expressão regular pra me ajudar?

```
$(function() {
    $("#buscar-menu").keyup(
        function() {
            var menuBuscado = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
                $(".menu-busca li").css("display", "block");
                $(".menu-busca li").each(function() {
                            if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(
                                    menuBuscado.toUpperCase()) < 0) {
                                $(this).css("display", "none");
                            }
                });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível criar uma função para esse determinado caso, que seria a remoção dos acentos apenas na consulta, no exemplo abaixo introduzi uma função chamada [removeAcento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript) que irá receber um parâmetro(string) e retornar a mesma string sem os acentos, basta fazer isso no input digitado e no texto recuperado dentro da função `each` do jquery.

Ficando parecido com isso:

```
function removeAcento(text){       
    text = text.toLowerCase();                                                         
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÁÀÂÃ]','gi'), 'a');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÉÈÊ]','gi'), 'e');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÍÌÎ]','gi'), 'i');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÓÒÔÕ]','gi'), 'o');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÚÙÛ]','gi'), 'u');
    return text;                 
}

$(function() {
  $("#buscar-menu").keyup(
    function() {
      var menuBuscado = removeAcento($(this).val().toUpperCase());
      $(".menu-busca li").css("display", "block");
      $(".menu-busca li").each(function() {
      if (removeAcento($(this).text()).toUpperCase().indexOf(
        menuBuscado.toUpperCase()) < 0) {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

---

#### Referência:

[Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)

[glmxndr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118437/glmxndr)

Comment: Eu não ia negativar, mas me perdoe, eu tive, porque eu acho muito incorreto a atitude de alguns usuários de pegar algo pronto e colar na resposta e nem no mínimo creditar os autores ou a postagem original que lhe ajudou em parte do código. Peço que sempre o faça, porque as pessoas merecem algum reconhecimento, assim como se você formular um código e outra pessoa usar ela também deve lhe citar, não é regra, mas é uma questão de cordialidade. Prometo até lhe positivar se o fizer e por favor não leve pro lado pessoal, é apenas uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Outra sugestão, esse código não é bom, recomendo tentar outros mais completos, que incluem `ç` ou usando o proprio `NFD` (veja sobreo  NFD e outros em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, pode ter sido descuidado e ignorante com o "criador" dessa função de minha parte, mas não faço a mínima ideia de quem seja o autor, uso essa função em meu código a anos para corrigir esse mesmo problema da pergunta à cima, para as próximas perguntas antes de usa uma função que não criei irei pesquisar se acho o autor, muitas vezes pode ser até difícil pela quantidade de função duplicadas que deve existir, mas obrigado pelo conselho de citação do autor, irei prestar mais atenção isso, criticas construtivas sempre são bem vindas!

Comment: Em codecs nada é perfeito de se controlar, a não ser que tudo seja muito bem feito por parte do autor da pergunta, é claro, mas de qualquer forma uma sugestão que possa resolver melhor, maiusculos, minusculos, utf vs iso-8859-1/latin e outros seria o uso disto https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/1518921, se editar a resposta eu posso remover o downvote, pq depois de 40 min não é mais possivel remover a não ser q vc edite, é um bloqueio do sistema. Fico no aguardo

Comment: Feito, adicionado como referência ao código